# C# Get TFS Kanban Board Column for each Work Item

Tags: c#, tfs, workitem, kanban

I have my WorkItemStore collection. I need to do an action on each WorkItem within. While I am iterating through I need to get the BoardColumn it is in. Pretty simple, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to get the WorkItem to tell me it's BoardColumn.

```
        // Get our WorkItem Store
        TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection = GetTfsProjectCollection(tfsCollectionUri);
        WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)projectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));

        // Run a query for all Tasks on the "New Creative Work" Board.
        WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(
            "Select [State], [Title] " +
            "From WorkItems " +
            "Where[System.AreaPath] = '<MySysAreaPath>' " +
            "AND[System.BoardLane] = '<MyBoardLane>'" +
            "AND[System.State] Does Not Contain 'Completed'");

        foreach(WorkItem item in queryResults)
        {
            string myBoardColumn = item[DO NOT KNOW WHAT GOES HERE]...
            //DO Stuff > Update db record
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: What version of TFS are you querying?

Comment: Hello Dave, I am using TFS 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to upgrade your TFS to TFS 2015 Update 1 and later, as in TFS 2015.1 and later version, the Board Column field has been enabled in work item queries. You can easily query and display of Kanban fields in a work item query.

To get TFS Board Column field for each Work Item in a query, please refer to the code snippet below:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System;

namespace GetWorkItemField
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/teamprojectcollection"));
            var service = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            string workItemQueryString = "Select Id, Title From WorkItems Where [System.TeamProject] = 'TeamProject'";
            var workItemQuery = new Query(service, workItemQueryString);
            WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemQuery.RunQuery();

            foreach (WorkItem item in queryResults)
            {
                var t = item.Fields["System.BoardColumn"];
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Title, t.Value);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do have TFS 2015, and I do understand that I can do a query on BoardColumn, but in this way I would have to enumerate the columns. However this is not the best option, because the column names could change, and then the code would have to be updated. The optimal approach is to get all my workitems on my board, and then as I go through each one to ask the work item which column it belongs to at the time of the query. Do you know if there is a way to do this? Sorry if I misunderstood.